# Manjaro gnome to cinnamon environment

Tags: linux, gnome, cinnamon, manjaro, desktop-environments

I have a manjaro gnome and i was trying to install cinnamon using terminal all operations were successful then when logged out of gnome and switched to cinnamon nothing showed up shortcuts work but no menus or even a background although i did exactly what the manjaro wiki was saying.
These are the commands i used:
**Sudo pacman -S cinnamon
sudo pacman -S cinnamon-wallpapers cinnamon-sounds gnome-terminal parcellite.**
This is my first post so forgive the poor reduction,any support would be much appreciated.

Comment: I love Cinnamon and Manjaro does a fine job with its distribution. Look in 'Community' releases. You'll find the iso download there.